# ORA-12899 value too large error while trying to drop a NUMBER column

Tags: oracle

I am trying to drop a column from a table in Oracle using a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "MY_TABLE" DROP COLUMN "ENABLED";
```

but I am getting this error:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "MY_TABLE"."ENABLED" (actual: 184, maximum: 22)
```

The column is defined as

```
"ENABLED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

and it only has values of 0 or 1 in all the rows.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error and how to drop the column?

Comment: For debugging, can you try:
Select * from MY_TABLE where ENABLED not in (0,1)

Comment: select for not in (0,1) returns no rows. no constraints on that column, it was just used as a simple flag

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete `create table` statement for `my_table`

Comment: Might you be hitting bug 17325413?

Comment: try to set it unused first, then drop unused columns.  See [Marking Columns Unused](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables006.htm#i1006709) for more

Comment: @tbone: setting it unused worked! no idea why. if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting it unused first, then dropping unused columns.  For more, see [Marking Columns Unused](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables006.htm#i1006709).

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have some rows with incorrect encoding, you may want to try a FLIP/FLOP:

-Create a table `NEW_MY_TABLE` with the same structure as `MY_TABLE`, but without `"ENABLED"` Column.

-Make an `Insert Into NEW_MY_TABLE (col1,col2...) Select (Col1,Col2...) from MY_TABLE`

-`Rename MY_TABLE to MY_TABLE_OLD`

-`Rename NEW_MY_TABLE to MY_TABLE`

-`Drop MY_TABLE_OLD`